# relative layout, text takes image space while sending

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

While send message the text and image takes same space of the relative layout they are in , how to set different size for text and image

I have attached the image, the spacing of image and text are in size of relative view

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/messages_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"

        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/default_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="299dp"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/message_text_background"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_image_view"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_a[enter image description here][1]lignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't use static numbers. use constraint layout.... or understand how match_parent works. u might need to add some code in there to make the text smaller/ add a '...' at the end f the string.

Comment: by using static numbers, you are limiting yourself to specific devices. this will be very bad if a device you DID NOT test uses the app.